# How does JAXB decide which type to create when it marshals XML that can match both types?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML schema whose topmost element is Document

```
<xsd:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
```

It contains one element of type ZZ_Customer which is restriction of Customer.
Both of these elements contain children of the same name but with slightly different types.

```
<xsd:complexType name="Document">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CstmrCdtTrfInitn" type="ZZ_Customer"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="ZZ_Customer">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="Customer">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="GrpHdr" type="ZZ_Group"/>
                    <xsd:element name="PmtInf" type="ZZ_Payment" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>                        
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Customer">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="GrpHdr" type="Group"/>
            <xsd:element name="PmtInf" type="Payment" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

When JAXB unmarshalls an XML file  will it create an instance of ZZ_Customer or will it create an instance of Customer? Likewise when will it create an instance of Group or ZZ_Group?

I've noticed is that JAXB will instances of ZZ_* for certain parts of the XML but uses their base counter parts for other parts of the XML.

On what basis does it makes its decisions? It does not appear obvious which criteria that JAXB is using.

Unfortunately I have no control over the schema and its design.

Comment: The XML Schema you are showing is incomplete. You'll have to provide the definitions of Group and Payment with and without ZZ_ so that the XML Schema can be compiled and the results can be investigated. --- Simple substitutions of types like csd:string for everything that's undefined result in xjc refusing to compile, which is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Document` has a property that corresponds to the sub-type.
The sub-type will be created when unmarshalling.  This makes sense since in Java when a property is typed to the subclass you can't set an instance of the super class on it.

If the property had corresponded to the super type, by default JAXB would have unmarshalled it to an instance of the super type.  The XML can contain the `xsi:type` attribute to specify that the subtype is being used.